# Как найти конец и начало строки в TextBox

Tags: visual-basic

Не знаю как найти конец и начало строки по выделенной подстроке.

Comment: Код свой покажите, что сами намудрили, и более полную информацию предоставьте. Какой язык использовали? Телепатов тут нет!

Comment: VB6 , а код если бы был, то не было бы вопроса

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Выделенной кем? У textbox есть методы и callback'и, через них можно узнать о "выделении".

Comment: @Разработчик, что, что вы написали, похоже на ответ?)

Comment: У меня следующая задача:  есть textbox в котором есть строки некого текста. Я делаю поиск в textbox по известным мне словам и происходит выделение этих слов в textbox. как найти конец и начало строки по выделенной подстроке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле SelectionStart - позиция начала выделения. SelectionLength - длина выделенного фрагмента

Comment: У меня как раз это есть, просто если есть выделенное слово в строке-как выделить всю строку?
Пример : "я хочу узнать, что за строка?"
Набираю в поиске "строка" - это слово выделяется - как сделать, чтобы выделялась вся строка?

Answer (score 0):

Поиск слова

```
 Dim Pozition As Integer = 1 ' В переменной хранится позиция курсора 
If InStr(Pozition, LCase(TextBox2.Text), LCase(Trim(TextBox1.Text))) <> 0 Then ' При помощи функции InStr в TextBox2 ищем текст введенный в TextBox1, функции LCase нужна для перевода всех символов в нижний регистр, т.е. это для того чтобы искался текст не зависимо от того в каком регистре символ(короче, ПриВет и пРИвЕТ будет искаться одинаково). Функция Trim нужна для обрезания пробелов слево и справо. Переменная Pozition задает позицию курсора(по умолчания Pozition = 1, т.е. поиск будет с первого символа)
    TextBox2.Focus() ' TextBox2 передаем фокус 
    Dim ftp As Integer = InStr(Pozition, LCase(TextBox2.Text), LCase(Trim(TextBox1.Text))) - 1 ' Устанавливаем позицию курсора перед найденным словом. Всё дело в том, что если в тексте было найденно искомое слово, то функция выдает позицию этого слова(т.е. количество символов перед искомым словом в тексте). 
    TextBox2.SelectionStart = ftp  ' Устанавливаем позицию курсора
       TextBox2.SelectionLength = Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) ' Выделяем найденное слово(выделение начинается с позиции курсора, и длится столько, сколько символов в слове)
    TextBox2.ScrollToCaret() ' Прокручиваем текст до выделенного слова
    Pozition = TextBox2.SelectionStart + Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) ' Переменная Pozition = позиции найденного слова, это для того чтобы одно слово не искалась по несколько раз 
Else ' Если ни чего не найденно(или поиск закончен), то выдаем сообщение и устанавливаем значение переменных по умолчанию 
    MsgBox("Поиск завершен")
    Pozition = 1
End If
```

Получение значения строки

```
Dim tempArray() As String, counter As Integer
tempArray = TextBox2.Lines   '  Набор строк

MsgBox(tempArray(TextBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(TextBox2.SelectionStart) + 1).ToString()))
```